# Add item to the beginning of the list

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I've been using the following code to add new comment to the end of the list:

```
 ractive.push('BlogPosts.BlogPostId.Comments', newComment);
```

But now I need to add an item to the beginning of the list. I've looked through ractive documentation but did not succeed in finding the appropriate method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use unshift method of array:

```
ractive.unshift('BlogPosts.BlogPostId.Comments', newComment);
```